# Relation between first fundamental form and $||\mathbb{X}_u\times\mathbb{X}_v||$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathbb{X}(u, v)=S$ be a regular surface and $p$ a point that lays in $S$. $T_PS$ is the tangent plane to $S$ in $p$ and $T_pS=\langle \mathbb{X}_u, \mathbb{X}_v \rangle$. The normal vector to the surface in $p$ would be 
$$\textbf{N}=\frac{\mathbb{X}_u\times\mathbb{X}_v}{||\mathbb{X}_u\times\mathbb{X}_v||}$$
where the functions are evaluated at the pertinent values. Is there any way I can relate $||\mathbb{X}_u\times\mathbb{X}_v||$ with the first fundamental form? I am not quite sure if $||\mathbb{X}_u\times\mathbb{X}_v||=\sqrt{EG-F^2}$ is true but I've checked a couple of cases and it worked, but maybe I was just lucky.

Comment: You mean $\|X_u\times X_v\|$, of course. Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Consider the matrix $A$ whose columns are $X_u$, $X_v$, and $\mathbf N$. Compute $A^\top A$ and $\det(A^\top A)$. Now interpret 
$\det A$ as the volume of a parallelepiped, which in this case is the (signed) area of the parallelogram spanned by $X_u$ and $X_v$ (why?). But what is the geometric meaning of $\|X_u\times X_v\|$?